# Ruby exercise regarding currency

Tags: json, ruby

I would be thankful for any help as I'm really stuck at the moment. I'm new to Ruby.

Just for some background, I've been given a method which is:
`CurrencyExchange.rate(date, from_currency, to_currency)`

I have to use the above method and I can't change the given method. The purpose is to convert one currency to another currency within a JSON file.

I also have a JSON file that contains dates, currencies (eg CZK, SGD...) and values. Here's a section of the JSON file:

```
"2018-11-22": {
"USD": 1.1403,
"JPY": 128.8,
"BGN": 1.9558,
"CZK": 25.99,
"DKK": 7.4616,
"GBP": 0.88598,
"HUF": 321.52,
"PLN": 4.3004,
"RON": 4.6593,
"SEK": 10.3035,
"CHF": 1.1351,
"ISK": 141.2,
"NOK": 9.7398,

...
```

Each value shown above is that currency in Euros. I have already done the next part which was two form two formulae:

Convert a given value to Euros (1 Euro)

I have a second formula to convert between any two currencies. eg PLN to RON - I have a way to calculate the exchange rate and I've been working on that.

I have read and parsed through the JSON file. I have a variable called `currency_data` that I've stored the key value pairs in.

What I need to do is come up with a way to ensure that if I enter a date (key) and two currencies a floating point number is returned, which matches my two formulae.

This is an example of the test:

```
def test_non_base_currency_exchange_is_correct
correct_rate = 1.2870493690602498
assert_equal correct_rate, CurrencyExchange.rate(Date.new(2018,11,22), "GBP", "USD")
end
```

What's the best way to approach this? Should I create methods for both formulae?

I would be very grateful for any help at all. Thanksss a million.

Comment: You need to show us what you actually attempted so far. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Your question is unclear... what exactly is it you are trying to do? Does the method you've been given not work, or are you trying to create it? You need to think about the logical steps. ie "Get exchange rate for currency A at date", "Get exchange rate for currency B at date". That can easily be implemented as a single function. Then the function it seems you have been tasked to create would simply call that function for each currency on the same date, and divide the rates. A good tip is to forget everything you know and think about the simplest steps to explain it to someone else from start.